# MVC routings not working when use ng-include

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have created an MVC page which renders razor views by using ng-include. 
The page is working fine but MVC routing is not working.

Simply the address bar is changing correctly but not redirecting to the relevant page and also I noticed even MVC actions methods are not firing. I'm using angular 1.0

here are [MVC controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxIzo.png) and relevant action methods. I am using MVC partial view with ng-include. Partial view rendering and all the angular data binding are happening clearly. after ng-include works, other MVC action methods are not working but the address bar is changing.

here is the [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZFP9.png)  that I used ng-include to render the partial view
here is the [MVC Partial View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGoqd.png) that ng-include calls.

---

```html
<ul ng-if="company.Children.length > 0" ng-init="CompanyHierarchy = company.Children">
    <li ng-repeat="company in CompanyHierarchy" ng-include src="'@Url.Action("CompanyTree", "Hrm")'">
 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: This isn't any where near enough information for us to help you.  Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask